How to make Microsoft OpenSSH daemon start automatically in Windows Server 2022?
I have just installed Windows Server 2022 in a VM. Then I have added the feature "OpenSSH"; that is, I have installed the Microsoft OpenSSH daemon that is shipped with Windows Server.
I have set the OpenSSH service startup type to "Automatic" and have configured the OpenSSH daemon as needed. Everything works as expected when I manually start the OpenSSH service after the VM has come up. However, the OpenSSH service does not start automatically when the VM is rebooted.
The same happens when I change the OpenSSH service startup type to "Automatic (Delayed start)".
What do I need to do to make the OpenSSH service start automatically upon reboot?
The only idea I have is that this service may rely on other services. In the "dependencies" tab of the service configuration, there are no other services listed, but this may be a mistake of the installer.
Could somebody give me a tip?

Have you checked the event log to see if there are any events indicating that the OpenSSH service tried to start and failed? At the very least, that would tell you if there was an unmet dependency.

The only idea I have is that this service may rely on other services. that's probably the easiest way to start. Make it dependent on the network or TCP/IP. Or add a scheduled task to start it 10 minutes after startup ...
